# How do I move data in my production server to a database on my test server : MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, replication, database-replication

I have data in a table `A` on my prod server. I want to move the data in it into table `A` (same name) on my test server.

What is the simple way to do this without exporting the data into some file and then inserting into my test table?

Thanks. I Looked around S/O and couldnt find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: I do mysql dumps as this is by far the simplest way to achieve your goal. Setting up a replication takes 5 minutes too

Comment: You want to **move** the data?  Did you mean to say copy?

Comment: Why the ban on using a file? There is probably some hidden feature request there, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a tool like SqlYog, it's pretty simple with a couple of clicks of the mouse, otherwise you cannot do it because a query works in the context of a db connection, and for different servers you need different connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you have phpmyadmin installed on both servers do the follwing

1. go to the table in phpmyadmin on your prod server
2. click export and export as .sql
3. go to the table in phpmyadmin on your test server
4. click import and upload the .sql file

If your database is more than 8 mb you can always compress it